# how to generate signal to stop execution of other processes in distributed model

Tags: algorithm, mpi, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Problem is to search a string of maximum length of 10bytes in a file of size 20gb. File contains one string in one line. I am writing parallel programming to do this. I just divided the file into p processes of about (Number of bytes in the file / P) bytes and read this much chunk by all processes parallely. After this i searched a string in all the processes at the same time.

So i just want to stop searching in all the other processes when meanwhile i get match of string in any one process, to get benefit of parallel programming.

How we can stop execution of other processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the most elegant way, but once one process found a matching string, it can [MPI_Isend()](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Isend.html) to all processes that no more work needs to be done.

Every process will check once in a while using [MPI_Iprobe()](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Iprobe.html) if there is a msg waiting, and if there is: accept it using [MPI_Rccv()](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Recv.html) and the process can now terminate itself elegantly.

Comment: Thanx for such a useful answer. As i went through MPI_Iprobe() function to check if there is any msg waiting using its FLAg parameter. Assume flag is set and i want to receive the msg But problem is in MPI_recv() function. Here i have to pass source process rank But i dont know which process will found a matching string because i have p processes are running in parallel.

Comment: @Gopal: You can use MPI_ANY_SOURCE as the source field

Comment: can we pass MPI_ANY_SOURCE as source rank in MPI_Recv() function?

Comment: yes, and in your recv() function you might also use the specific source, since you have it in the MPI_Status you sent to Iprobe()

Comment: thnx ...which one should i use MPI_Recv() or MPI_Irecv()?

Comment: It doesn't matter, since you do it only after you already used `MPI_IProbe()`, and the flag indicated there is a msg waiting anyway. Both should yield same result with same performacne.

Comment: i am able to abort execution of all other processes by checking flag of MPI_Iprobe(). But i am getting following one run time error in all prcesses ***An error occurred in MPI_finalize *** after MPI was finalized ***MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (goodbye) [abc :27791] abort before MPI_Init completed successfully; not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed! i dont know how it is coming. If possible Plz fix it!!!!

Comment: to solve the above pbm I used MPI_Abort(comm, 911); to abort the execution of all processes. Then i got one msg in the last line of all the process::[abc :27792]  MPI_Abort invoked on the rank P in communicator comm with errorcode 911. What is meaning of this msg?

Comment: @Gopal: Ask a new question with more details on the specific problem. I will check if I know the answer. If not - I am sure someone else will.